# MySQL count when value is not equal

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have few tables.
    1.region
    2.restaurant
    3.restaurant_itmes

**region**

```
id | name
................
1  | NY
2  | Paris
3  | London
```

**restaurant**

```
id | name     | region_id
.........................
1  | KFC      | 1
2  | McDonals'| 1
3  | La res   | 2
4  | Queen's  | 3
```

**restaurant_items**

```
id | name | restaurant_id | pro_pic   | featured_pic
...................................................
1  |Pizza |3              | null      | defaut.jpg
2  |Pizza |4              | pizza.jpg | defaut.jpg
3  |Burger|1              | burger.jpg| burger.jpg
4  |Burger|2              | burger.jpg| burger.jpg
5  |Burger|3              | null      | burger.jpg
6  |Burger|4              | null      | default.jpg
7  |Donat |2              | null      | default.jpg
8  |Fries |2              | null      | default.jpg
```

I want to generate an query to populate this table

```
region  |Number of restaurants  |total items | items_with_pro_pic | items_with_featured_pic
............................................................................................
NY      |   2                  |    4       |       2             | 2
Paris   |   1                  |    2       |       0             | 1
London  |   1                  |    2       |       1             | 0
```

What I have done upto now is

```
SELECT region.name, count(restaurant_items.id) as total_items, count(restaurant_items.pro_pic)
INNER JOIN restaurant on restaurant_items.restaurant_id = restaurant.id
INNER JOIN region on restaurant.region_id = region.id
GROUP BY region.name;
```

Here I can get items_with_pro_pic by count(restaurant_items.pro_pic)
but I can't do that for items_with_featured_pic because featured_pic is not null able if there is no value
default value is default.jpg.
So I tried `count(restaurant_items.featured_pic != 'defaut.jpg')` but this doesn't work for me.

And how could I get number of restaurants since it is not a part of restaurant_items table?

How do I achieve these two using MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `COUNT` to a `SUM` and run it over an IF statement:

```
SUM(IF(restaurant_items.featured_pic != 'default.jpg',1,0))
```

Or alternatively you can specify it as a `COUNT` if you want, but the ELSE portion will need to be a NULL rather than a 0 since otherwise it will still count it:

```
COUNT(IF(restaurant_items.featured_pic != 'default.jpg',1,NULL))
```

To count number of restaurants, you can simply do a distinct count:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT restaurant.id)
```

A few small extra tips:

- You may want to change the name of 'restaurant_items' to 'restaurant_item' since that suits the naming convention of the other tables
- You should be aliasing your table names in the FROM and JOIN clauses, since it enhances code legibility

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works for me. If I want to count items without professional picture. (pro_pic is null) How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

use case when

```
    SELECT region.name, count(restaurant_items.id) as total_items, count(restaurant_items.pro_pic),
    count(case when restaurant_items.featured_pic != 'defaut.jpg' then 1 end) as 
    items_with_featured_pic,
    count(case when pro_pic is null then 1 end) as 
    items_with_pro_pic_null
    INNER JOIN restaurant on restaurant_items.restaurant_id = restaurant.id
    INNER JOIN region on restaurant.region_id = region.id
    GROUP BY region.name
```

Comment: If I want to count items without professional picture. (pro_pic is null) How do I do that?

Comment: @PathumSamararathna, added it to my answer - you can check

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression to produce `null`s instead of `default.jpg` in order to use in a `count` function:

```
SELECT     region.name, 
           COUNT(restaurant_items.id) as total_items,
           COUNT(restaurant_items.pro_pic),
           COUNT(CASE WHEN restaurant_items.featured_pic != 'default.jpg' THEN 1 END)
INNER JOIN restaurant ON restaurant_items.restaurant_id = restaurant.id
INNER JOIN region ON restaurant.region_id = region.id
GROUP BY   region.name;
```

Comment: If I want to count items without professional picture. (pro_pic is null) How do I do that?

Comment: @PathumSamararathna You can use a `case` expression to find them: `count(case when pro_pic is null then 1 end)`.